# Swift enum as array index

Tags: swift, enums

Maybe I misunderstand enums in swift, but in obj-c I was using enums like this (and using a lot):

```
class SomeObject;

typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, SomeType) {
    Type1 = 0,
    Type2,       // = 1
    Type3,       // = 2
    TypeInvalid  // = 3
};

- (SomeType)getTypeOf(NSArray *a, SomeObject *o) {
    //for (int i = 0; i < a.count; ++i)
    //    if ([a[i] isEqual:o])
    //        return i;
    NUInteger result = [a indexOfObject:o];
    return result == NSNotFound ? TypeInvalid : result;
}

// Also I could use this:
a[Type3] = someObject;
```

How to do the same in Swift? Am I forced to use constants (`let Type1 = 0`), like in Java (`public static final int Type1 = 0;`)?

Comment: Rather than looping and calling `isEqual:`, just use `indexOfObject:`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply:

```
enum SomeType : Int {
  case Type1, Type2, Type3, TypeInvalid
}
```

The Apple documentation states:

> By default, Swift assigns the raw values starting at zero and
>   incrementing by one each time

So you get Type1 with a `rawValue` of `0`.  For example:

```
  1> enum Suit : Int { case Heart, Spade, Diamond, Club }
  2> Suit.Heart.rawValue
$R0: Int = 0
  3> Suit.Club.rawValue
$R1: Int = 3
```

Note: In your example code, you'll need to replace `return i` with `return SomeType(rawValue: i)!` (although I don't quite understand the logic as apparently `i` is limited by `a.count` which might not correspond to a `SomeType` value)

Answer (score 3):

In addition to [Ed Gamble response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37075875/469218), you can also set enum values manually:

```
enum SomeType : Int {
  case Type1 = 1
  case Type2 = 2
  case Type3 = 3
  case TypeInvalid = -1
}
```

Using Swift enums you are not limited to `Int` values:

```
enum SomeType : String {
  case Type1 = "Type 1"
  case Type2 = "Type 2"
  case Type3 = "Type 3"
  case TypeInvalid = "Invalid type"
}
```

---

To get the inner value, you call `rawValue`:

```
let foo = SomeType.Type2
foo.rawValue // returns "Type 2"
```

And you can construct enums from values using `init(rawValue:)` method:

```
let rawValue = "Type 2"
let foo = SomeType(rawValue: rawValue)
```

Note that this `init` returns an optional, because it may not found a valid enum associated to that value. Having a default value makes error handling much easier:

```
let foo = SomeType(rawValue: rawValue) ?? SomeType.TypeInvalid
```

Comment: Thanks for the addition, but what `??` does?

Comment: `??` is the [nil coalescing operator](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html). `a ?? b` unwraps the value of `a` if is not `nil` and returns `b` otherwise. It's equivalent to `a != nil ? a! : b`. In this case, `SomeType(rawValue:)` may not match and return `nil` and will return `.TypeInvalid` in that case.